# My PC will only boot to BIOS when I switch positions of the physical RAM or I clear the CMOS

Tags: boot, memory, motherboard, bios

I'm fixing a PC for a friend. At first it was issues with Windows OS. I successfully reinstalled Win10 on it, and can boot into it only by removing and placing the RAM in its slot or by clearing the CMOS by removing and placing that mobo battery.

I was doing testing with only the core components (CPU, CPU cooler, mobo, PSU), but now I attached the SSD, HDD, and PCI wifi card. I doubt these 3 components would make these worse.

This is the build in use: https://pcpartpicker.com/user/Jahames/saved/#view=fx26Mp

On PC Part Picker, they state: "Warning: Some Intel H81 chipset motherboards may need a BIOS update prior to using Haswell Refresh CPUs. Upgrading the BIOS may require a different CPU that is supported by older BIOS revisions."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting here and looking at the Saved parts listed I used back then helped me fix this by realizing that warning is a thing. I visited https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-H81M-DS2V-rev-10#support-dl put the BIOS update on a flash drive. Install the update through the BIOS. Works perfect.

Apparently the mobo didn't support the CPU in use with Win10.